# header view when QFileSystemModel is displayed in a QTableView

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

when the contents of the QFileSystemModel is displayed in a QTableView , the alignment of the text in the first row header section is right-aligned ,while the others is left-aligned,I wonder why ?
[image]

how to make the alignment of the text in each header section to be left-aligned?

setDefaultSectionSize() seems doesn't work here

my code

```
import sys   
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

if __name__ == '__main__':   

    app =QApplication(sys.argv)      
    ui =QMainWindow()   

    model= QFileSystemModel ()      
    model.setRootPath(QDir.currentPath())  

    model.sort(3)

    table = QTableView()
    #print(table.verticalHeader().defaultAlignment()) #
    table.verticalHeader().setDefaultAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)

    table.setModel(model);   
    table.setRootIndex(model.index(QDir.currentPath())) # 
    ui.setCentralWidget(table)
    ui.resize(800, 600)
    ui.show()      
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Can you check what the model returns from headerData(), when requesting the Qt::TextAlignmentRole?

Comment: model.headerData(0, Qt.Vertical, Qt.TextAlignmentRole) returns 1.

Comment: model.headerData(0, Qt.Horizontal, Qt.TextAlignmentRole)  returns 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the `QFileSystemModel` in my own code and was surprised to see you get this strange behaviour. Then I dug deeper and saw that I had actually subclassed the `QFileSystemModel` and overridden the `headerData` method.

It seems that when `role` is `Qt.DecorationRole` and `section==0` the default `headerData` function returns a `QImage` which messes things up. Also, `setDefaultAlignment` doesn't seem to actually set the default alignment.

In your case the problem will go away if you use the class given below. You can specify the alignment in the constructor to MyFileSystemModel (e.g.  `model= MyFileSystemModel(h_align = Qt.AlignRight)`)

```
class MyFileSystemModel(QFileSystemModel):
    def __init__(self, h_align = Qt.AlignLeft, v_align = Qt.AlignLeft, parent = None):
        super(MyFileSystemModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.alignments = {Qt.Horizontal:h_align, Qt.Vertical:v_align}

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role==Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            return self.alignments[orientation]
        elif role == Qt.DecorationRole:
            return None
        else:
            return QFileSystemModel.headerData(self, section, orientation, role)
```

Comment: If the default headerData is returning a random image as the first element, that's a bug that would need to be reported. `setDefaultAlignment` is called on the *view*, not on the *model*, so the model has nothing to honour there.

Comment: If `setDefaultAlignment` doesn't have anything to do with the model then why did you ask for the OP to check `headerData` output for `TextAlignmentMode`? To me it seems that `setDefaultAlignment` has no effect on either the model or the view. I didn't check the implementation of `setDefaultAlignment` but the only way I managed to actually change alignment was by setting it in `headerData`.

Comment: @peppe. Not a bug: more of an ugly hack. For obscure reasons, the current implementation deliberately returns a blank image for the first section. It seems that using the model in a tableview simply exposes this hack.

Comment: @ardoi. Your solution seems good, but for improved compatibility it would be better to return `None` for the `DecorationRole` because `QVariant` will not always be available (e.g. by default it's not for python3).

Comment: @ardoi: because I assumed that `setDefaultAlignment` sets the default alignment, i.e. the one the view honours if the model doesn't specify otherwise.

Comment: @ekhumoro: still a model isn't supposed to use such hacks for ... whatever reason. I call it a bug. Edit: [the source](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/dialogs/qfilesystemmodel.cpp.html#_ZNK16QFileSystemModel10headerDataEiN2Qt11OrientationEi), which triggers even more than one "wth is going on".

Comment: @peppe. It's only a bug if you didn't mean it :-) Anyway, the person who wrote the actual code left the following comment: "oh man this is ugly and doesn't even work all the way!"...

Comment: @ekhumoro didn't know about python3 and `QVariant`. I've replaced it with `None`

Comment: In the doc of PyQt ,it says "None will be interpreted as an invalid QVariant."